# iOS UI tests find object using accessibilityIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I want to create some UI tests for my iOS app and everything seems to work, but there is one problem. I have view controller that displays register form which is built using UITextField objects. I have set accessibleIdentifier for every text field in storyboard but my test is unable to find the last text field. I don't understand it because all textfields are very similar to each other.

Any ideas?

I'm using Swift if this matters.

Comment: You need to give more information. Like what error comes up on the screen. Maybe an image of your story board. Or the code for the text fields. What do you mean by it can't find the last text field. Does it not show when you run the app or you can't get data from that text field?

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem solved. The last text field was for enter password and turns out that if you mark "Secure Text Entry" in storyboard you have to query for this element in .secureTextFields, not in .textFields